# KVL with current source

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

Can someone explain how to do KVL in this circuit?

Comment: is R2 connected directly to R5?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Ivica, it looks like you have two \$R_4\$-marked resistors. I'm deciding that the one next to \$V_2\$ is actually \$R_3\$. A current source has infinite impedance. This means that \$R_4\$ and \$R_5\$ (being in series) are irrelevant. You can remove them by shorting them without any meaningful change (unless you care about the voltages across the current sources.) Both \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$ are summing together at the (+) end of \$V_3\$. So you know the current in \$V_3\$ and its direction. \$V_3\$ is similarly irrelevant. Ground the (-) end of \$V_1\$. It's now completely trivial.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't use KVL around a loop that has a current source in it. If you are trying to use the mesh-current method of analysis, and you have a current source that is part of two meshes, then you would need to make a supermesh that encloses the current source.

Comment: There is never a need for super-meshes or super-nodes. It is always possible to never learn about those and still apply the traditional techniques. The underlying theories didn't rely on such ideas and they are bullet-proof without them. Of course, there's no reason not to simplify. For example, \$R_5\$ is pointless and can be shorted and removed without loss.

Comment: It's a question from the exam, can you explain how to solve it please?

Comment: No, I won't give you the solution. You need to make an effort to solve it yourself and tell us where exactly you get stuck.

Comment: I asked for explanation, not solution.

Comment: I gave you an explanation: if a current source is in two meshes, make a supermesh.

Answer (score 1):

Your schematic reads to me as having two \$R_4\$-marked resistors. I'm choosing to name the one next to \$V_2\$ as \$R_3\$.

A current source has infinite impedance. This means that \$R_5\$, being in series with \$I_1\$, is irrelevant and can be shorted out for analysis purposes. This also means that \$R_4\$, being in series with $I_2$, is likewise irrelevant and can be shorted out for analysis purposes.

As both \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$ sum to a junction where there is only \$V_3\$ attached, \$V_3\$ is likewise also irrelevant as you know its current is \$I_1+I_2\$ and the direction is ***into*** the (+) terminal of \$V_3\$. \$V_3\$ and be shorted out and removed for analysis purposes.

I get to pick a node as ground, too. So your schematic is down to these two equivalent circuits for analysis:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4q6MN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Which is super-simple to solve. And once you solve it, you can add back all the removed parts and assign voltages where you may with the simplest of ease.

But let's assume you are stuck with mesh analysis (KVL) and you absolutely have to use your circuit without a single simplification for analysis purposes. You don't want to make it easy. You want to force yourself to do it the hardest way possible.

Then let's redraw the schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdjf86.png)</sup>

Looking at the right-hand schematic above, there are just three loops you need to apply: the upper left-hand corner loop, the upper right-hand corner loop, and the bottom loop. You can choose the direction you want for each loop's current. But if it were me, I'd probably use the existing directions indicated by the two current sources for the loops they are part of (and I'd name those loops accordingly, too.) And I'd make the upper left-hand corner loop go clockwise and I'd call that current \$I_3\$. But you don't have to do that. You can select any direction you want. Just be consistent about it, once you've made your decisions.

Normally, this would mean you have three equations and three unknown currents to solve. But in this case, you already know two of the loop currents as the current sources determine them. This leaves only one unknown loop current. But three equations, yes? The difference is that you now need to solve for the two unknown voltages across those two current sources. So when you write down your mesh equations, be sure to indicate those two voltages as unknown variables. Assign them a polarity (as you choose) and then construct the KVL equation just like you always do.

When done, you will still have three simple equations and three unknowns. The only oddity at all is that you will need to solve them for one unknown current and two unknown voltages. Other than that, it's the same as always for mesh analysis.

For example, let's walk around the upper-right loop (clockwise so that it follows the direction of \$I_2\$) and then the bottom loop (counter-clockwise so that it follows the direction of \$I_1\$.) I'll consider the (+) end of either \$I_1\$ or \$I_2\$ to be the end pointed at by its arrow.

$$\begin{align*}
0\:\text{V} + V_{I_2}-R_4 \cdot I_2 -V_3-R_2 \cdot\left(I_2-I_3\right) &=0\:\text{V}\tag{$I_2$}\\
0\:\text{V} + V_{I_1} -R_5\cdot I_1 - V_3-R_3\cdot\left(I_1+I_3\right)+V_2 &= 0\:\text{V}\tag{$I_1$}
\end{align*}$$

Can you now develop the final equation for the third and final upper left-hand \$I_3\$ loop, which I assumed in the above equations went *clockwise*?

*Note:* Counter to what Elliot Alderson says here, there's no need for super-mesh analysis. There never is, never was. Neither superposition (additive property of linear systems) nor homogeneity require the idea. I never use a super-mesh or a super-node. Not ever. And I never will. They are not needed and, in my opinion, only serve to either confuse people or else impress them. I consider them without any value whatsoever (except perhaps when reading something others have written which uses those ideas.)

Comment: I'm happy for you that you never need to use a supermesh. They are a pain in the ass. However, it is common to ask students to demonstrate that they know how to use mesh analysis. In that case they really don't have the option to ignore the instructor and do it jonk's way. Please note that I did not say that this was the best way to analyze the circuit, I said...

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Read your answer again. See what you are asserting.

Comment: "If you are trying to use the mesh-current method". I would appreciate it in the future if you do not put words in my mouth or assume that I have some motivation that I have not stated.

Comment: "and you have a current source that is part of two meshes". I did not assume, as you did, that simplifying the circuit was allowed.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I didn't accuse you of any motivation. I simply stated that I don't agree with you answer's claim that "you can't use KVL around a loop that has a current source in it." It's just not true.